# How to hide DialogFragment from showing again when moving between fragments android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment

I have two `Fragments` let it be `Fragment A` and `Fragment B`. In `Fragment A` I use `viewModel.items.collect {}` to get data from database. Inside the `collect {}` the user sees a `DialogFragment`. The problem is that when I go to `Fragment A`, I see this dialog, then move to `Fragment B`, then go back to `Fragment A` and see this dialog again, although this is not a good. Is it possible to somehow make it so that when returning back from `Fragment B` to `Fragment A`, this dialog is not shown?

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.items.collect { 
        MyDialog().show(childFragmentManager, MyDialog.TAG)
    }
}
```

Comment: in which method of fragment you have added this code ?

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani in onViewCreated()

Comment: can you try to move this code to ```onCreate``` of fragment along with your viewmodel intialisation code

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani Yes, I tried to do this, but the application crashes with an error: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani There is a reason why it is very important for me to use viewLifecycleOwner - my dialog is not called immediately, but on a specific timer. I can open Fragment A, then open Fragment B, at which point the timer expires and the app crashes because the dialog was called in the wrong fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that property items of your viewmodel is type of StateFlow. If it's true you should change to SharedFlow. StateFlow remembers the last emitted value and emits it for all new subscribers, so when you start collecting you get an event that triggers your dialog but when you back to that Fragment collect is called once again and dialog is triggered again. By default SharedFlow does not repeat the last value and is the best option for one-time events.

Comment: yes, it really works fine, but there is a nuance. I checked and if I go to fragment B, the event will occur, I will return back to fragment A and the dialog will no longer appear. How to deal with it?